# JPA CriteriaBuilder case query

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

Can anyone provide an example of how to write a case query using `CriteriaBuilder`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What follows is a sample case expression using `CriteriaBuilder` (this works in JPA 2):

```
Hashtable caseTable = new Hashtable(3);
caseTable.put("Bob", "Bobby");
caseTable.put("Susan", "Susie");
caseTable.put("Eldrick", "Tiger");
Expression expression = builder.get("firstName").caseStatement(caseTable, "NoNickname").equal("Bobby");
```

It generates the following `SQL` query:

```
"CASE t1.firstName WHEN 'Bob' THEN 'Bobby' WHEN 'Susan' THEN 'Susie' WHEN 'Eldrick' THEN 'Tiger' ELSE 'NoNickname' END = 'Bobby'"
```

For more info please see [JPA 2.0 Case Expressions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/case_expressions).

Answer (score 6):

I could not find "caseStatement" in JPA 2.0 Criteria API.  Seems its EclipseLink specific.
The correct way is to use "builder.selectCase()"

See the section "Case Expressions" in [Pro JPA 2: Mastering the Java Persistence API](http://www.apress.com/9781430219569)

Comment: I am sorry. Updated the link  :)